# Member registration not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a small website, non-members can register with the website, when they register their details should be stired in the database table. I had this working but now it is not, it does everything apart from store the details in the database. Can anyone help please?

```
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="test"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="members"; // Table name

       // Connect to server and select databse.
        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

     // username and password sent from form
   $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
   $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
   $repeatpassword=$_POST['repeatpassword'];

   // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
   $myusername = strip_tags($myusername);
   $mypassword = strip_tags($mypassword);
   $repeatpassword = strip_tags($repeatpassword);
   $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
   $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
   $repeatpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($repeatpassword);


   if($myusername&&$mypassword&&$repeatpassword)
    {
        if ($mypassword==$repeatpassword)
        {
            if (strlen($myusername)>10)
                {
                header("location:erroruname.php");
                }
                else
                {
                if (strlen($mypassword)>10||strlen($mypassword)<5)

                header("location:errorpword.php");

                else 
                {

                $queryreg = mysql_query("

                 INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('','$myusername','$mypassword')
        ");
            session_register("myusername");
            session_register("mypassword");
            header("location:insertdetail.php?myusername=" . $username);            
        }
        }

}
else
    header("location:errornomatch.php");
     }
      else
              header("location:errorfields.php");
```

Comment: never ever store passwords as plain text

Answer (score 2):

This was never working because you aren't specifying any column names in your `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('','$myusername','$mypassword')
```

Needs to look like

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name(`column_a`, `username`, `password`) 
VALUES('','$myusername','$mypassword')
```

Comment: you don't need to specify column names.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an auto-increment column in that table? If so, don't use the `' '`, instead, don't enter anything at all. In that case, you *should* specify only the two columns (username and password).

Comment: thanks but still not working, very confusing as it was previously working

Answer (score 0):

echo the query and run manually the sql query in phpmyadmin

```
echo "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('','$myusername','$mypassword') "; die();
```